# Does Ivy-Gen Work on Animated Meshes

Tags: geometry-nodes

Does the Ivy-Gen tool work on a deforming or animated mesh, or can it be applied only to static objects?  I have found no examples of it being used on an animated character, for instance.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you be more specific of desired result? Some reference ...

Comment: Hi!  Yes, as the question implies, I'd like to have some vines growing along the limbs of an animated character.   Having been unable to find a single example of anyone doing that [not saying they haven't - I just haven't found any], I began to wonder if the tool were limited to operating only on static meshes.

In another forum, someone mentioned using Deformers or Geometry Nodes.  I will be looking into any and all options, but I've only had Blender for a few days, and have a lot to learn about it still.

Comment: Please include important parts into your Q not into the comment. Yes, Mesh Deform modifier or GeoNodes sounds the way, for beginner sounds to me a big bite. I asked for details, because just let move Ivy with mesh can be done with modifier, but it is another story for growing (you mentioned now) or if you expect some parts of branches (or leaves) should wave as reaction on a mesh movement ... growing along limbs - how the beginning should looks like? Or is it out of camera view? To give you something see answer ...

Answer (score 1):

### Geo Nodes

One of the option based on *Shortest Path* node ... this could work, just as name whisper ... it can be a glitchy since transforming vertices by armature could change state of what os shortest path for GN :)

[image]
[image]
[Original post](https://nenghuo.gumroad.com/l/wzlkmv?layout=profile)

To make it work select a vertex of grow beginning (on your limb object) and *Assign* it to *Vertex Group*  called "StartPoint" (or call it as you want , just choose the same name listed under GN Atribute node.

### Edit:

To avoid re-shortening path (mentioned above) you can split the node tree into two separate stages ...

**First Step**
use beginning of the node tree. It builds vines structure ... *Apply* modifier.

[image]
[image]

**Second Step**
Assign to this structure the second part of the node tree ... plus add *Armature* modifier to this as well with enable *Bind to > Bone Envelops*

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably beginner friendly "old school" way ...

**Ivy Generator**
Enable build in addon Ivy Generator. *Add New Ivy* (with setup fits your needs).

**Cage**
To by able animate it with the limb you can use **Mesh Deform** modifier, but for that you need a "cage object that covers all Ivy vines ...

- Duplicate your limb model add *Solidify* modifier and try to cover all Ivy vines (if there are still some out of the cage you can fix that manually later)
- add *Remesh* modifier with some lower resolution just to simplify cage
- *Apply* modifiers (and manually or by sculpting adjust shape of cage to cover all vines)
- Select cage object and than *Armature* object and parent them (Ctrl+P) *Armature Deform With Automatic Weight* ... so now your cage follow the same animation of your limb.

Now select Ivy object and add *Mesh Deform* modifier > *Object* set your cage object and press *Bind*

**Grow Animation**
Simple one can be achieved under Curve Properties > Geometry > Start&End ... just set value O for beginning frame (keyframe) and value 1 (keyframe) for last frame of grow.

[image]